# Not updating posts Parse Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform

In my parse database, I have some data created within the app, but when I go to the TableViewController showing the posts, it hasn't updated for some off reason. Here is my code (I can provide more info on the parse database if needed to help solve this issue):

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import ParseUI

class PostsTableViewController: PFQueryTableViewController {

    override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {

        let query = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
        query.cachePolicy = .CacheElseNetwork
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
        return query
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell? {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PostsTableViewCell

        let posterUsernameText = object?.objectForKey("createdBy") as? String
        cell.posterUsername.setTitle("\(posterUsernameText)", forState: .Normal)

        cell.msgTextView.text = object?.objectForKey("text") as? String

        let imageFile = object?.objectForKey("image") as? PFFile
        cell.cellImageView.file = imageFile
        cell.cellImageView?.loadInBackground()

        return cell

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        if indexPath.row + 1 > self.objects?.count {

            return 44

        }

        let height = super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
        return height
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        if indexPath.row + 1 > self.objects?.count {

            self.loadNextPage()
            tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        } else {

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetail", sender: self)

        }
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {



        }

    }

}
```

EDIT: Here is a photo of my database, and a photo of my screen:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: [self.tableView reloadData]; ?

Comment: Where would I put it so I works on pull to refresh? And i'm  guessing viewdidload for start up? Also swift please

Comment: Yes sorry. Try to add a button to refresh data. self.tableView.reloadData()

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to reload the data for the PFQueryTableView & you do that with the loadObjects method. As mentioned on Parse's documentation, it clears the table and loads the first page of objects. (You can use loadNextPage to load the next page of objects onto the table view) Here is a [link](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQueryTableViewController.html#/c:objc(cs)PFQueryTableViewController(im)loadObjects) to the PFQueryTableViewController's documentation

Comment: Is this in swift by any chance?

Comment: No unfortunately Parse is somewhat slow on updating for Swift and some of the documentation is Obj-C only. You would have to call self.loadObjects() [self referring to PFQTV]. I have used Parse + Swift a couple times in the recent past with table views (didn't use PFQTV) and would store it in an array and after I would just reload the table ( using tableName.reloadData() )

Comment: For reference: https://github.com/Nexmo/ToDo-iOS/blob/2FA/NexmoToDoList/TableViewController.swift

Comment: Adding these did not make much of a difference. Nothing new loaded.

Comment: Did you import Bolts.framework? That seems to be a common issue around the PFQTV not loading the data.

Comment: Yes I do have bolts.framework, it just has a ? next to it.